# Unity: Publics don't show up in default references/inspector..?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I've been trying for hours now, but I have no idea what is wrong.

Normally, when you define a public object/var in Unity C#, it shows up in the inspector or default references where you can drag something to it.

Here's my test code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

[Serializable]
public class modGlobals : MonoBehaviour {

    public static GUIStyle defaultMask;
    public GUIStyle trollo;

}
```

Aaaaaand...

[image: Object doesn't show up]

I tried several options, wrote the thing in MonoDev as also in Visual Studio, put all my files in an namespace, w and w/o Serializable attribe but.. What could be wrong?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I guess its shows when you will attach this script to any game object than you would be able to access this variables in inspector.

Comment: Could be, yes. I haven't tried it out yet. But I need a global script with objects that I can access from everywhere (different scenes) w/o attaching it to an game object in every scene.

Comment: You don't need to mark a MonoBehaviour as Serializable.  Don't use public fields; use the [SerializeField] attribute.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do need to attach it to a gameObject in the scene in order to show the public members in the property inspector, since your script inherits from MonoBehaviour.

This is what I got.
[image: The property inspector in scene view.]

Additionally, you cannot expose static members in the property inspector - even when marked as SerializableAttribute. System.SerializableAttribute is not valid on this declaration type. It is valid on `class, struct, enum, delegate' declarations only.

In relation to your comment about requiring a globally accessible script with objects, you have a couple options, such as

- Singleton script attached to gameObject ([example](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32861/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-static-objects-and-singletons-in-unity/32868#32868)), set with [DontDestroyOnLoad()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) so it persists between scene changes.
- Static class